# Pokemon X and Y Hacked Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I got a shiny Rayquaza on Pokémon White 2. It has the normal ability, and normal stats/moves, but it was caught in Sinnoh on level 41. I would like to know if it is hacked, would it affect my Pokémon X game? Would the save file corrupt?

Comment: Legal as in legitimately acquired?

Comment: As in 'legally' hacked.

Comment: I know the difference between hacked and legit, but the legal Pokemon are confusing me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'legal', because illegal means forbidden by law, and I don't think anything in the pokemon games is forbidden by any country's law :D

Comment: @Kevin he probably means legal in tournaments. And if that is the case, they don't accept any illegitimately acquired Pokemon to my knowledge, so no, it wouldn't be legal. If that's not what he means, though, I have no clue.

Comment: Re-reading the second comment there: No hacked Pokemon is considered 'legal' that I know of. Even if the only hack is for shiny and level, it is still hacked and, from what I recall, in the wrong region. I don't recall being able to get a Rayquaza in Sinnoh, but I could have missed an event. Even still, hacked, as far as I know, will never equal legal.

Comment: This question is oddly worded, but the intent is clearly to ask if that shiny Rayquaza can be used in a tournament (where legendaries are permitted), or if it will get caught by the anti-cheating system.

Comment: @Nolonar That's about what I was thinking. And even if the system didn't catch it, if it was entered at that level, someone would surely notice. I've never done a tournament, but I'm sure that they would have a way to notice a low-level Rayquaza, and from Sinnoh. So unless there was an event, as I said, it would be caught would be my guess.

Comment: @Kendra, that's what I thought. I'm certain its hacked, but I'm wondering if I could trade it to Pokémon X and Y. I've seen reviews of Pokebank, and I'm beginning to believe I can trade it over. If I did, and it is hacked, will anything happen to my game?

Comment: Nothing will happen to your game, you just can't use it in competitive battles. In the game itself is fine. But Pokebank is currently delayed, so you'll have to wait a bit still. Personally, I think using anything hacked takes the fun from the game, but that's just me, and this isn't some super OP hack, so... It works out for just in-game.

Comment: Would your actual question perhaps be "Would anything bad happen if I get a hacked Pokemon into Pokemon X and Y through Pokebank, assuming it got through?"

Comment: Word is pokebank isn't even noticing hacked pokemon, and they easily pass through. There really is no way to tell if it's hacked/illegitimate or not, unless it's something absurd.

Comment: Thank-you! I have noticed that Pokebank is another failed attempt at stopping hacked Pokémon. But if I can trade it over, even if it can't participate in tournaments, then that makes me happy. I made sure to level it up fairly, and its stats are the usual for those on level 100. Now if it were OP hacked, I wouldn't trade it over.

Comment: @Jerry, yes, that would be my question.

Comment: PokeBank hasn't even launched yet, has it?

Comment: @KernelPanic It launched in Japan, to my understanding, it was just the Western release that was delayed.

Comment: It wasn't launched in America yet, but I'm preparing.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to transfer hacked/altered pokemon from Gen V games to Pokemon X/Y will not result in any save file corruption or ban. I speak from experience, since one of my traded pokemon in Pokemon Black 2 was flagged as hacked by the PokeTransporter and was excluded from the transfer. (If you are curious it was a Japanese Torterra I had traded through GTS)
This does not corrupt the Gen V or the X/Y game.

**If your pokemon is detected as a hacked/illegal pokemon, it will just stay in your Gen V game, and won't be transferred through Poketransporter. No side-effects occur.** I recommend releasing that pokemon to never be bothered by it again.

Answer (score 0):

It will not as much effect your game file, due to the fact that the Pokebank will be used to trade it over. If the rayquaza is indeed a fake, the Pokebank will **not** allow it to be traded!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they would think it was hacked. If it was a low level and legit they wouldn't have a problem. Now if it was hacked in and it was level 100 and shiny that's a different story. If it was that then they would notice it. But if it isn't you should be fine. I'm glad to help.